# Vue and Vuex are reacting to data change differently

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a normalized tree data structure, like following:

```
{  
‘1’: {    
   uid: ‘1’,  
   value: null,  
   children: [‘2’]  
 },  
 2’: {   
   uid: ‘2’,  
   value: ‘Child text’,  
   children: []
 }  
}
```

Then I have a custom component that renders the first element and renders children recursively. The state tree is initialized with only the first element in the beginning, then during render, it generates new elements by using `children` array.

When generating the second element and adding it to the tree with `Vue.set(state, uid, elem)`, Vuex is re-rendering the first element as well. If I don’t use Vuex, then it works as expected.

Please see what I’m doing wrong in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5yrc4v0/5/), it’s a small script, just change the `use_vuex` boolean variable to see with and without Vuex and see the console log in render function.

Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend that you put these objects `{    
   uid: ‘1’,  
   value: null,  
   children: [‘2’]  
 }` in an array. Because array.push and array.pop have native reactivity.

Comment: Could you add the code of your component (how you render state)?